# Why did I gain +1 reputation because of "removed"? What was removed?

Tags: support, reputation, reputation-history

I got +1 today because "removed". I haven't seen this kind of change before; why did I get +1?

[image: +1 - 4 hours ago - removed]

Comment: Most likely an answer that you downvoted has been removed and your reputation (1) you lost doing that had been restored.

Comment: Thanks, I think this is the answer.

Comment: Kudos to you for down voting answers that aren't worth keeping around.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Downvoting an answer costs you 1 reputation.

When an answer you have downvoted gets removed, you regain that point of reputation you spent downvoting it.

From the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) on when you gain (and lose) reputation:

> you vote down an answer: −1